# releasing a NSMutableArray is causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

so when i try to run the following code, i end up with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. it happens when i try to release a NSMutableArray retrievedAnalysisDataList. the array is a list of retrievedAnalysisData objects. if i try to either release the data list or if i set up the init with an autorelease, i get the same result. i'm kinda guessing it has something to do with the sorting section of the code since i don't have this issue with the retrievedAnalysisIDarray.

any ideas?

```
if (tempDict != NULL) 
    {
        NSMutableArray *retrievedAnalysisDataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *retrievedAnalysisIDarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (id key in tempDict)
        {
            retrievedAnalysisData = [[RetrievedAnalysisData alloc] init];

            retrievedAnalysisData.createDate = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"createdate"];
            retrievedAnalysisData.ID = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"id"];
            retrievedAnalysisData.mode = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"mode"];
            retrievedAnalysisData.name = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"name"];
            retrievedAnalysisData.numZones = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"numzones"];
            retrievedAnalysisData.srcImg = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"srcimg"];
            retrievedAnalysisData.type = [[tempDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"type"];

            //NSLog(@"\n createDate: %@ \n id: %@ \n mode: %@ \n name: %@ \n numzone: %@ \n srcimg: %@ \n type: %@", retrievedAnalysisData.createDate, retrievedAnalysisData.ID, retrievedAnalysisData.mode, retrievedAnalysisData.name, retrievedAnalysisData.numZones, retrievedAnalysisData.srcImg, retrievedAnalysisData.type);

            [retrievedAnalysisDataList addObject:retrievedAnalysisData];
            [retrievedAnalysisData release];
        }

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
        sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createDate" ascending:YES] autorelease];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        NSArray *sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList;
        sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList = [retrievedAnalysisDataList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        int count = [sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            retrievedAnalysisData = [[RetrievedAnalysisData alloc] init];
            retrievedAnalysisData = [sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList objectAtIndex:i];

            [retrievedAnalysisIDarray addObject:retrievedAnalysisData.ID];
            [retrievedAnalysisData release];
        }

        dataCenter.sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList = sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList;
        dataCenter.retrievedAnalysisIDarray = retrievedAnalysisIDarray;

        [retrievedAnalysisIDarray release];
        [retrievedAnalysisDataList release];

        dataCenter.isRetrieve = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [picker reloadAllComponents];

        picker.hidden = FALSE;
        pickerToolBar.hidden = FALSE;
        toolBar.hidden = TRUE;
        innerCircle.hidden = TRUE;
        outerCircle.hidden = TRUE;
        trackLabel.hidden = TRUE;
        displayGPSLabel.hidden = TRUE;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in this section of code:

```
        retrievedAnalysisData = [[RetrievedAnalysisData alloc] init];
        retrievedAnalysisData = [sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList objectAtIndex:i];

        [retrievedAnalysisIDarray addObject:retrievedAnalysisData.ID];
        [retrievedAnalysisData release];
```

The first line allocates a new RetrievedAnalysisData, but then the second throws that away (leaking it) and places an object fetched from the array in the `retrievedAnalysisData` variable instead. You don't own this object fetched from the array, and you don't take ownership by calling `retain`. So the `release` on the fourth line is incorrect, releasing an object that you do not own.

Then when you release your NSMutableArray, it tries to release the object again and you get a crash because the object is already released.

To fix it, get rid of the useless first line, and also get rid of the incorrect release.

Comment: Ok, changed the code and it worked. ran an analyze and with releasing the data list, the leak is gone! thank you very much, this is an issue i have in a couple places in my code so i am very appreciative. i'm still fairly new to obj-c and learning, just started using custom objects.

would you be able to further explain what happens in the original code? i create a new RetrievedAnalysisData object but how do i throw it away when i try to assign it a RetrievedAnalaysisData object from my sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the memory management of all your properties, it’s hard to see exactly what’s going on. But take a look here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        retrievedAnalysisData = [[RetrievedAnalysisData alloc] init];
        retrievedAnalysisData = [sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList objectAtIndex:i];

        [retrievedAnalysisIDarray addObject:retrievedAnalysisData.ID];
        [retrievedAnalysisData release];
    }
```

You call `-release` on an autoreleased object (`retrievedAnalysisData`). Try this instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        retrievedAnalysisData = [sortedRetrievedAnalysisDataList objectAtIndex:i];

        [retrievedAnalysisIDarray addObject:retrievedAnalysisData.ID];
    }
```